# 400 error returned when using Box2.0 Delete method

Tags: box-api

I am using Box 2.0 API to delete a file.  Using Postman, i enter the following:

https://api.box.com/2.0/files/2605672883

specifying the DELETE action.  I've set the authorization header appropriately.  When I submit the request, I get the following error:

{
    "type": "error",
    "status": 400,
    "code": "bad_request",
    "help_url": "http://developers.box.com/docs/#errors",
    "message": "Could not parse JSON",
    "request_id": "4934716064fff2a0a70988"
}

This makes me think that i need a JSON object as part of the message body, the documentation specifies that the File ID is the only thing necessary as part of the request.  Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong ?

thanks

Answer (score 3):

DELETE /files/{id} requests require ([as of last week](http://developers.blog.box.com/2012/07/13/more-v2-updates/)) an `If-Match` header with the sha1 of the file in order to prevent race conditions. You can see the updated documentation here: http://developers.box.com/docs/#files-delete-a-file

EDIT: There is a bug in POSTMAN in how it sends DELETE requests. If you send an empty JSON object `{}` as the body, it should work successfully.

Comment: This is a bug in POSTMAN. See my comment abouve.